# Python3: Conditional extraction of keys from a dictionary with comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I need to extract those keys of a dictionary whose values pass a certain condition. 
Basically, I want to do this, only in a shorter, more pythony way:

```
keys=[]
for key in dict:
    if dict[key]==True:
        keys.append(key)
```

This was my original idea, but it raises a ValueError:

```
[key for (key,val) in map if val==True]
```

I came up with this for the moment, but I can't help feeling it's not very nice:

```
[key for key in map.keys() if map[key]==True]
```

Is there a less messy way to it? Perhaps something obvious that I'm clearly missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to get the keys with true values that is a lot shorter and cleaner than a comprehension (not that comprehensions are bad though):

```
>>> dct = {0:False, 1:True, 2:False, 3:True}
>>> list(filter(dct.get, dct))
[1, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: You don't need `dct.keys()` - iterating over a dictionary yields the keys already. Use `dct`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`dict.items()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

```
[key for key, val in dct.items() if val]
```

If you want to take only the keys with `True` values, rather than any true-ish value, you can use an equality check:

```
[key for key, val in dct.items() if val==True]
```

It is noted in [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) though, that one shouldn't compare boolean values using `==` - so don't use it unless you absolutely need to.

Also, please don't name variables `dict` or `map` (even if it's for demonstration purposes only) because they shadow the bulitins.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a mapping yields only keys. Use `map.items()` instead.

Comment: The question is labeled (in the title) Python 3, so `dict.iteritems()` doesn't exist.